# ReactJS Consuming REST API using Fetch

Tags: reactjs, rest, api

My sample API reflects the follows:

```
[
    {
        "$id": "1",
        "Id": "000-000-000",
        "crgName": "Walmart - 08/29/2018 - Standard ",
        "crgStarteddatetime": "2018-08-29T08:40:40",
        "crgScore": {
            "$id": "2",
            "Value": 171160002
        }
    },

]
```

...so I'm able to show the crgName and crgStarteddatetime using the following lines of code:

```
<ul>
    {audits.map(item => (
        <li key={item.crg_buildingid}>
            <b>Building Name</b>: {item.crgName} |<b>Start Date</b>: {item.crgStarteddatetime} |
        </li>     
     )}
</ul>
```

...my question is (looking back at my API): How do I display the id and value from crgScore?

Comment: try `item.crgScore.$id` and `item.crgScore.value`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ul>
                {audits.map(item => (
                  <li key={item.crg_buildingid}>
                    <b>Building Name</b>: {item.crgName} |<b>Start Date</b>: {item.crgStarteddatetime} |
 <b>crgScore ID</b> {item.crgScore['$id']} | <b>Value</b> {item.crgScore['Value']}

                  </li>

                ))}
                </ul>
```